# iOS Quickblox get rooms related to user

Tags: ios, xmpp, quickblox

I would like to know if I can retrieve all the chat rooms in which a user is present. I have got Member type rooms and they are persistent. In the SDK and samples the way to get rooms is by using...

```
[[QBChat instance]  requestAllRooms];
```

As I said earlier I would like to retrieve only user present-in rooms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This method return all application rooms

I propose to build some logic around CustomObjects module http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios

For example, create a class with name **ChatRoom** with fields **name** and **occupants_ids** and manage all related things